# How to return geospatial distance results for geo_shapes in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, geospatial, distance, elasticsearch-geo-shape

I have two indices, both have > 2 million documents containing `localId`s (mapped to `keyword`) and geospatial data. Both indices use `geo_shape` as the mapping), so the mappings look like this:

```
{
  "properties": {
    "localId": {
      "type": "keyword"
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "geo_shape"
    }
  }
}
```

I've successfully run bounding box queries against the data, but I'm struggling to run the distance from point queries. [The docs give explicit examples of the query running against geo_shape data](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-geo-distance-query.html), but I get an error of:

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "query_shard_exception",
        "reason" : "field [geometry] is not a geo_point field",
        "index_uuid" : "e7-HPZmUR4Wpu96W6K_YXw",
        "index" : "test1"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "search_phase_execution_exception",
    "reason" : "all shards failed",
    "phase" : "query",
    "grouped" : true,
    "failed_shards" : [
      {
        "shard" : 0,
        "index" : "test1",
        "node" : "FAu7pbAtQti7e9aRaX4-bg",
        "reason" : {
          "type" : "query_shard_exception",
          "reason" : "field [geometry] is not a geo_point field",
          "index_uuid" : "e7-HPZmUR4Wpu96W6K_YXw",
          "index" : "test1"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

Any idea what I've missed to be able to get distance working against geo_shape data?

elasticsearch details:

```
{
  "name" : "server-name",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "cluster_uuid" : "1SqVbKmGR5qxG6bcpjxasg",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "7.10.2",
    "build_flavor" : "oss",
    "build_type" : "deb",
    "build_hash" : "747e1cc71def077253878a59143c1f785afa92b9",
    "build_date" : "2021-01-13T00:42:12.435326Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "8.7.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.8.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `geo_distance` query in 7.10 [only supported `geo_point` fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.10/query-dsl-geo-distance-query.html).

The support for `geo_shape` [started in 7.11](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.11/query-dsl-geo-distance-query.html)